# Display IBA ebooks inside iOS apps?

Tags: ios, ibooks

Is it possible to display an IBA file (as created with Apple's iBooks Author on OS X) inside an app? Apparently `UIWebView` is not able to render the format.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one component that natively supports it. Since it's a modified EPUB file, you could unzip it and render the html and js inside in a UIWebView.